# How to refer to a file/dir in a different directory substructure?

Tags: java, recursion, path, directory

I need to recursively compare he contents(including all the subfolders) of two folders(source and target) selected by the user. The contents must be put into TreeViews which will show how do the files/dirs in them compare to each other using some kind of color marking or some such. The relations are:

```
Exists in source, but not in target -> new, copy over to target
Exists in target, but not in source -> deleted, delete from the target
Exists in both, but binary unequal -> changed, copy over from source
Exists in both, and is binary equal -> unchanged, leave be
```

The problem, however, is somehow referring to the other directory while recursively going through one of them. Example:

```
Source: C:\somewhere\fooSource
Target: C:\somewhereElse\barTarget
```

Now, the recursive call on the source folder found C:\somewhere\fooSource\aSubfolder. How do I get Java to put together the path C:\somewhereElse\barTarget\aSubfolder, so that the program can for example check for existence or do a binary comparison (if it's a file)?

EDIT, some of the skeleton of the implementation:

```
@FXML
private void handleCompareButton() {
    if (sourceFile.exists() && targetFile.exists() && !sourceFile.equals(targetFile)) {
        for (File i : sourceFile.listFiles()) {
            if (i.isFile()) {
                if (/*the equivalent file in the other directory**/.exists()){
        /*do the checks for binary equality**/
                }
            }
/*some recursive calls to another function in case it's a directory**/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you show us some source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend :)..
heres something i found pretty similar to what you need... 
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/Utilityclassforsynchronizingfilesdirectories.htm